# Go back to the parent if

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have this kind of code

```
if(a == 3) {
  if(b == 4) {
    // do somthing
  } else {
    // do an other thing  
  }
} else {
  // do the same other thing  
}
```

I wondered, when I am in the first `else`, how could I go to the second `else`because it will execute the same code

Thank you

Comment: it could be done by creating a method with the same code and executing it.

Comment: it will not go back to the second `else` because if the first if statement is true it will go to the nested if

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only want the `// do something` part to be executed when `a==3` AND `b==4`, so you can combine them with an `&&` operator.

This way you can merge the two conditions into one, and have a single `else` clause that performs the `// do an other thing` part :

```
if(a == 3 && b == 4) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do an other thing  
}
```